# Declaring inside for loop

Tags: java, variables, scope

```
   for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        in.close();
        for( i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
```

This shows error that i is not intialized.

```
 for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        in.close();
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
```

And this works.Can anyone explain why?

Comment: A variable declared in a `for` loop only has scope inside that loop.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `i` (in the first example) is only the first `for` loop. Declare `i` before the first loop, and you can do (as you seem to want)

```
int i;
for(i=0; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = in.nextInt();
}
in.close();
for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
    System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
}
```

**Also**, I would prefer to use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (instead of embedding `in.close()` there).

Comment: Thanks but i didnt understand about the 'try with resources'.

Comment: @Gokul It's a link.

Answer (score 0):

In java there is a concept of block level scope,means that i is limited to its for loop only.So next time you have to initialize it before using it or you could initialize it at class level to allow it to be used as much as you want.